# Shairport stutters with Comfast (RTL8188CUS) WIFI dongle

Tags: networking, shairplay

Shairport works fine playng a song via AirPlay from an iPad when the Raspberry Pi is connected through Ethernet, but stutters and stops when using a Wifi Comfast dongle based on the RTL8188CUS chipset. Terminal and VNC access  become unusable too. Has anyone found this problem?

Comment: It could be that the amount of traffic you're trying to do is overwhelming the Pi due to poorly written drivers. Have you checked CPU usage (top), bandwidth usage (iftop), and available bandwidth (iperf)?

Comment: iperf showed 5MBps as client and 0.3Mbps as server. I had similar results when testing the dongle on a Windows 7 machine, so I returned it. Ordered another based on the RT3070, will report when I test it. Thanks!